# singleton session asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session, singleton

i have user settings fetched on user login and storing them in singlton session, below is the code.
It is per user not application wide. Earlier I was storing static object in session and it was shared across all users, now I have created singleton session.

Is the below code thread safe.

```
 public string FirstName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
 public string LastName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

 public static Users Currentuser
    {
        get
        {
                HttpSessionState session = HttpContext.Current.Session;
                lock (padlock)
                {
                    if (session["UserInfo"] == null)
                    {
                        session["UserInfo"] = new Users();
                    }
                }
                return (Users)session["UserInfo"];
            }
   }
```

I am creating new session for each request,saving retrieving values from it.

Comment: Isn't Session itself thread safe ?

Comment: yes it is,but the way i am creating the session object for current user and accessing i meant to ask.